# Immobilise Desktops

Tags: macos, applications, desktop, mission-control

I want to make my Desktops stay in an order that I want. I want to have my first 3 Desktops locked and others dynamic in example:

- I'm working on Desktop1. When an app is full screen the app is between Desktop1 and Desktop2 but I want it to open after Desktop4 since the others mounted.
- I'm working on Desktop3. When I open an app from Dock(or cmd+tab) which is currently opened in Desktop1, Desktop1 and Desktop2 changes positions. I don't want this to happen I want to go to Desktop1 without changing the order.

Hope I explained clearly. Is there a way I can immobilise some Desktops.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can have them all static or dynamic but not a mix of both.  To make them static (so they stay as you put them) do this:

- Open **System Preferences**
- Click on **Mission Control**
- Uncheck **Automatically rearrange Spaces based on most recent use**

This will keep them as they are arranged by you.  To arrange them, drag them to the desired position after launching Mission Control.

[image: Mission Control settings]

Comment: nice one a + from me, keep them coming :)

Comment: Thanks, Buscar웃 I try to do what I can when I have time. ;)